# QoS on tunnel interface

Tags: cisco, qos

My configuration

```
policy-map Shape_FTP
 class FTP
  shape average percent 5
 class class-default
  fair-queue
policy-map Shaper
 class class-default
  shape average percent 100
   service-policy Shape_FTP

interface tunnel 0
 bandwidth 512
 tunnel protection ipsec profile aes
 service-policy output Shaper
```

Bandwidth value is used from physical interface. Is it possible to make QoS use bandwidth value from tunnel interface? I have a lot of tunnel interfaces with different bandwidthes (with the same tunnel source IP). I would like to use one policy map with `shape average percent 100` rather than a lot of with `shape average 512000` and so on

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried using [`bandwidth qos-reference`](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/qos/command/reference/qos_book/qos_a1.html#wp1027485)?

```
interface Tunnel100
 bandwidth 1000
 bandwidth qos-reference 1000
```

Comment: No, I haven't. Now it works. Tnx a lot!